# how to change _Visibility of FloatingActionButton for each ListView item individually?

Tags: flutter, dart

This question is a follow up to a previous post i made:

[How to apply Scroll controller for multiple SilverList or ListView items?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72130850/how-to-apply-scroll-controller-for-multiple-silverlist-or-listview-items)

In that post the error was resolved but the example i showed was not correct.

There is also a problem when scrolling horizontally on each `ListView()` items. When you scroll on one item then the `_Visibiltiy` of all the `FloatingActionButtons` of the other items are also affected.
[image]

My question is how can i only affect the `_Visibility` of one individual `FloatingActionButtons()` in `ListView()` be affected when scrolling on a individual `CustomScrollView()` generated inside `ListView()` and not affect the `_Visibility` of the other `FloatingActionButton()`?

I also might add that the `snapshot.data.length` varies from the data i  generate from the json. So there needs to be solution where i don't alter the data itself but rather the `_Visibility` should change inidividually based on json data.

This is all the code i use:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final ThemeData? themeData;
  const MyApp({Key? key, this.themeData}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: AppView2(),
    );
  }
}

class AppView2 extends StatefulWidget {
  const AppView2({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _AppViewState createState() => _AppViewState();
}

class _AppViewState extends State<AppView2> {
  late ScrollController _hideButtonController;
  var _isVisible;

  Future<void> generateList() async {
    String responseBody =
    await rootBundle.loadString("assets/tableJsonData.json");
    var list = await json.decode(responseBody);
    return list;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    generateList();
    _isVisible = true;
    _hideButtonController = ScrollController();
    _hideButtonController.addListener(() {
      if (_hideButtonController.positions
          .any((pos) => pos.userScrollDirection == ScrollDirection.reverse)) {
        if (_isVisible == true) {
          setState(() {
            _isVisible = false;
          });
        } else if (_isVisible == false) {
          Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 1000), () {
            setState(() {
              _isVisible = true;
            });
          });
        }
      } else {
        if (_hideButtonController.positions
            .any((pos) => pos.userScrollDirection == ScrollDirection.forward)) {
          if (_isVisible == true) {
            setState(() {
              _isVisible = false;
            });
          } else if (_isVisible == false) {
            Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 1000), () {
              setState(() {
                _isVisible = true;
              });
            });
          }
        }
      }
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text('DataTable'),
            ),
            body: FutureBuilder(
              future: generateList(),
              builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapShot) {
                if (snapShot.hasData) {
                  return ListView.builder(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                      itemCount: snapShot.data.length,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        return SizedBox(
                          height: 250,
                          child: Stack(
                            children: [
                              CustomScrollView(
                                controller: _hideButtonController,
                                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                                shrinkWrap: true,
                                slivers: <Widget>[
                                  SliverPadding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                                    sliver: SliverList(
                                      delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
                                        <Widget>[
                                          Center(
                                            child: Text(snapShot.data[index]
                                            ["long-text"]
                                                .toString()),
                                          )
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                              Visibility(
                                visible: _isVisible,
                                child: Align(
                                  alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                                  child: FloatingActionButton(
                                      child:
                                      const Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios),
                                      onPressed: () {}),
                                ),
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        );
                      });
                } else {
                  return CircularProgressIndicator();
                }
              },
            )));
  }
}
```

This is the json file i read from :

```
[
  {
    "long-text": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
  },
  {
    "long-text": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
  },
  {
    "long-text": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
  },
  {
    "long-text": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
  },
  {
    "long-text": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
  }

]
```

**Edit**

So i followed the answer of @SlowDeepCoder and edited my original code and i also added a controller  but i when i add the condition in the `ListView` i cannot init state in the app and i get error: `type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'bool'` 
This is all the code that is edited :

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:test_project/controllers/swipe_controller.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final ThemeData? themeData;
  const MyApp({Key? key, this.themeData}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: AppView2(),
    );
  }
}

class AppView2 extends StatefulWidget {
  const AppView2({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _AppViewState createState() => _AppViewState();
}

class _AppViewState extends State<AppView2> {
  late ScrollController _hideButtonController;

  var isVisible = true;
  Future<void> generateList() async {
    String responseBody =
        await rootBundle.loadString("assets/tableJsonData.json");
    var list = await json.decode(responseBody);
    return list;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text('DataTable'),
            ),
            body: FutureBuilder(
              future: generateList(),
              builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapShot) {
                if (snapShot.hasData) {
                  return ListView.builder(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                      itemCount: snapShot.data.length,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        isVisible = SwipeController().swipeHandler(isVisible);
                        return SizedBox(
                          height: 250,
                          child: Stack(
                            children: [
                              CustomScrollView(
                                controller: _hideButtonController,
                                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                                shrinkWrap: true,
                                slivers: <Widget>[
                                  SliverPadding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                                    sliver: SliverList(
                                      delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
                                        <Widget>[
                                          Center(
                                            child: Text(snapShot.data[index]
                                                    ["long-text"]
                                                .toString()),
                                          )
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                              Visibility(
                                visible: isVisible,
                                child: Align(
                                  alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                                  child: FloatingActionButton(
                                      child:
                                          const Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios),
                                      onPressed: () {}),
                                ),
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        );
                      });
                } else {
                  return CircularProgressIndicator();
                }
              },
            )));
  }
}
class SwipeController {
  swipeHandler(isVisible) {
    var _hideButtonController = ScrollController();
    _hideButtonController.addListener(() {
      if (_hideButtonController.position.userScrollDirection ==
          ScrollDirection.reverse) {
        if (isVisible == true) {
          isVisible = false;
        }
      } else {
        if (_hideButtonController.position.userScrollDirection ==
            ScrollDirection.forward) {
          if (isVisible == false) {
            isVisible = true;
          }
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

I still don't know how i can resolve the issue

Answer (score 0):

You can create a local variable in your ListView's itemBuilder to describe the visibility of the FloatingActionButton for each item. For example:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final ThemeData? themeData;
  const MyApp({Key? key, this.themeData}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: AppView2(),
    );
  }
}

class AppView2 extends StatefulWidget {
  const AppView2({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _AppViewState createState() => _AppViewState();
}

class _AppViewState extends State<AppView2> {
  late ScrollController _hideButtonController;

  Future<void> generateList() async {
    String responseBody =
    await rootBundle.loadString("assets/tableJsonData.json");
    var list = await json.decode(responseBody);
    return list;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _hideButtonController = ScrollController();
    _hideButtonController.addListener(() {
      if (_hideButtonController.positions
          .any((pos) => pos.userScrollDirection == ScrollDirection.reverse)) {
      } else {
        if (_hideButtonController.positions
            .any((pos) => pos.userScrollDirection == ScrollDirection.forward)) {
        }
      }
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text('DataTable'),
            ),
            body: FutureBuilder(
              future: generateList(),
              builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapShot) {
                if (snapShot.hasData) {
                  return ListView.builder(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                      itemCount: snapShot.data.length,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        final isVisible = Random().nextBool(); //Random visibility, update this condition to your own. 
                        return SizedBox(
                          height: 250,
                          child: Stack(
                            children: [
                              CustomScrollView(
                                controller: _hideButtonController,
                                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                                shrinkWrap: true,
                                slivers: <Widget>[
                                  SliverPadding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                                    sliver: SliverList(
                                      delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
                                        <Widget>[
                                          Center(
                                            child: Text(snapShot.data[index]
                                            ["long-text"]
                                                .toString()),
                                          )
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                              Visibility(
                                visible: isVisible,
                                child: Align(
                                  alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                                  child: FloatingActionButton(
                                      child:
                                      const Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios),
                                      onPressed: () {}),
                                ),
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        );
                      });
                } else {
                  return CircularProgressIndicator();
                }
              },
            )));
  }
}
```

And the _isVisible variable is not really useful and can be removed.

Comment: Is possible to show the full code with the changes? You can copy and paste the code on dart pad and then you can view the app. And then if you post url link i can see it too. Or you can post the full code here

Comment: I am asking this because i am not really sure what i should change and not change

Comment: I'm really trying but I have no idea how to get the gist from the dart pad to be able to share the link.

Comment: On this post its ok too, you can edit your original post

Comment: Alright I have updated the answer! The most important part is where the new isVisible is created. Having it inside the itemBuilder ensures that each item in the list will have its own isVisible variable.

Comment: I have edited my question because your solution does not work for me

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final ThemeData? themeData;
  const MyApp({Key? key, this.themeData}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: AppView2(),
    );
  }
}

class AppView2 extends StatefulWidget {
  const AppView2({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _AppViewState createState() => _AppViewState();
}

class _AppViewState extends State<AppView2> {
  late ScrollController _hideButtonController;

  var isVisible = true;
  Future<List<LongText>> generateList() async {
    var data = await http.get(Uri.parse('https://jsonkeeper.com/b/S97W'));
    List<LongText> list = jsonDecode(data.body)
        .map<LongText>((e) => LongText.fromJson(e))
        .toList();
    return list;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text('DataTable'),
            ),
            body: FutureBuilder(
              future: generateList(),
              builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<LongText>> snapShot) {
                if (snapShot.hasData) {
                  return ListView.builder(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                      itemCount: snapShot.data!.length,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        return SizedBox(
                          height: 250,
                          child: Stack(
                            children: [
                              CustomScrollView(
                                controller: snapShot
                                    .data![index].scrollContoller
                                  ..addListener(() {
                                    if (snapShot.data![index].scrollContoller
                                            .position.userScrollDirection ==
                                        ScrollDirection.forward) {
                                      setState(() {
                                        snapShot.data![index].isVisibile = true;
                                      });
                                    } else {
                                      setState(() {
                                        snapShot.data![index].isVisibile =
                                            false;
                                      });
                                    }
                                  }),
                                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                                shrinkWrap: true,
                                slivers: <Widget>[
                                  SliverPadding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                                    sliver: SliverList(
                                      delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
                                        <Widget>[
                                          Center(
                                            child: Text(
                                              snapShot.data![index].longText,
                                            ),
                                          )
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                              Visibility(
                                visible: snapShot.data![index].isVisibile,
                                child: Align(
                                  alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                                  child: FloatingActionButton(
                                    child: const Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios),
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      snapShot.data![index].scrollContoller
                                          .animateTo(
                                        snapShot.data![index].scrollContoller
                                            .position.maxScrollExtent,
                                        duration:
                                            const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                                        curve: Curves.easeOut,
                                      );
                                    },
                                  ),
                                ),
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        );
                      });
                } else {
                  return CircularProgressIndicator();
                }
              },
            )));
  }
}

class LongText {
  final String longText;
  LongText({
    required this.longText,
    required this.isVisibile,
    required this.scrollContoller,
  });
  bool isVisibile;
  final ScrollController scrollContoller;
  LongText.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : longText = json['long-text'],
        isVisibile = true,
        scrollContoller = ScrollController();
}
```

Comment: This does not work for me

Answer (score 0):

[image]

- User visibility per item Not on a global level
- User _scrollcontroller per item (locally) as you are using it globally. So common controller will assign to all.

Here I provide an example of that.

```
  import 'dart:convert';
  import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
  import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
  import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
  
  void main() async {
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    runApp(MyApp());
  }
  
  class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
    final ThemeData? themeData;
    const MyApp({Key? key, this.themeData}) : super(key: key);
  
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return const MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        home: AppView2(),
      );
    }
  }
  
  class AppView2 extends StatefulWidget {
    const AppView2({
      Key? key,
    }) : super(key: key);
  
    @override
    _AppViewState createState() => _AppViewState();
  }
  
  class _AppViewState extends State<AppView2> {
    late ScrollController _hideButtonController;
    List<String> listData = [];
    var _isVisible;
    String dummyText =
        "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.";
  
    Future generateList() async {
      listData = [dummyText, dummyText, dummyText, dummyText];
      return listData;
    }
  
    @override
    void initState() {
      generateList();
      _isVisible = true;
  
      super.initState();
    }
  
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return SafeArea(
          child: Scaffold(
              appBar: AppBar(
                title: Text('DataTable'),
              ),
              body: FutureBuilder(
                future: generateList(),
                builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapShot) {
                  if (snapShot.hasData) {
                    return ListView.builder(
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                        itemCount: snapShot.data.length,
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                          ScrollController _hideButtonController =
                              ScrollController();
                          _hideButtonController.addListener(() {
                            if (_hideButtonController.positions.any((pos) =>
                                pos.userScrollDirection ==
                                ScrollDirection.reverse)) {
                              print(_hideButtonController.positions.first);
  
                              if (_isVisible == true) {
                                setState(() {
                                  _isVisible = false;
                                });
                              } else if (_isVisible == false) {
                                Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
                                    () {
                                  setState(() {
                                    _isVisible = true;
                                  });
                                });
                              }
                            } else {
                              if (_hideButtonController.positions.any((pos) =>
                                  pos.userScrollDirection ==
                                  ScrollDirection.forward)) {
                                if (_isVisible == true) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    _isVisible = false;
                                  });
                                } else if (_isVisible == false) {
                                  Future.delayed(
                                      const Duration(milliseconds: 1000), () {
                                    setState(() {
                                      _isVisible = true;
                                    });
                                  });
                                }
                              }
                            }
                          });
                          return SizedBox(
                            height: 250,
                            child: Stack(
                              children: [
                                CustomScrollView(
                                  controller: _hideButtonController,
                                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                                  shrinkWrap: true,
                                  slivers: <Widget>[
                                    SliverPadding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                                      sliver: SliverList(
                                        delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
                                          <Widget>[
                                            Center(
                                              child: Text(snapShot.data[index]
                                                  .toString()),
                                            )
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                                Visibility(
                                  visible: _isVisible,
                                  child: Align(
                                    alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                                    child: FloatingActionButton(
                                        child:
                                            const Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios),
                                        onPressed: () {}),
                                  ),
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                          );
                        });
                  } else {
                    return CircularProgressIndicator();
                  }
                },
              )));
    }
  }
  
  class ListModel {
    String title;
    bool isVisible;
    ListModel(this.title, this.isVisible);
  }
```

Comment: Its a bit late but when i use this code all the arrows dissapear when i swipe one of the list items horizontally